# What should be the Origin URI while registering app for accessing UBER API

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

We have our app running on github. When I specify the Origin URI as

```
http://localhost:8888
```

the app works fine and returns the data. Now while testing the app on server I went to Uber's Manage app and tried changing Origin URI to http://vis-project-3.github.io but it says invalid Origin URI. I tried http://* and still says invalid URI. But it accepted https://* and this did not help me much because the git organization is on http. Any suggestions on this??

Answer (score 1):

Should be set to: https://foo.github.io, where foo is your github name.